# Can side-by-side installs of Ubuntu 17.10 share a common ZFS pool?

Tags: dual-boot, 17.10, zfs

I want to dual boot 2 copies of Ubuntu 17.10. Obviously, only one would be running at a time. Can they both share a data store on a common ZFS dataset? I assume no metadata is kept outside of the ZFS pool, such that one instance could have stateful knowledge not shared by the other instance.

What risks are there?
What best practices would I need to adhere to?
If not reasonable or possible, please articulate the reasons.

Clarification

By "share", I do not mean simultaneous live access as in "fileshare." Rather, I mean can they use the same ZFS dataset on a mutually exclusive basis, traded between them on between individual boot sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible, as long as you do not import the pool at the same time on two running Ubuntu instances.
But you have to force import the pool when switching the Ubuntu instance, since ZFS checks the hostid when importing the pool and normally fails if that does not match with the one stored in the pool.